# Conditional same-arity template class code, based on template arguements?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Kindof similar to [Conditional compile-time inclusion/exclusion of code based on template argument(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659064/).

(BTW Answer 2 in above question does not compile at all)

(C++11 and above)

I the following class description, would like Outer::Inner<...> to be a type, so as to used as template parameters, etc.

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer {
  __enable_if__(cond_1<T>()) {
    // Does not compile if T fails cond_1
    template<typename> Inner { ... }; 
  }
  __enable_if__(cond_2<T>()) {
    // Does not compile if T fails cond_2
    template<typename> Inner { ... }; 
  }
};
```

I could only think of sth. like below.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct BaseA { static constexpr int va = 111; };
struct BaseB { static constexpr int vb = 222; };

struct C : public BaseA {};
struct D : public BaseB {};

template<typename T>
struct Outer {
  template<typename, int selector> struct InnerImpl;

  template<typename S> struct InnerImpl<S, 1> { static constexpr int v = T::va; };
  template<typename S> struct InnerImpl<S, 2> { static constexpr int v = T::vb; };

  static constexpr int computeSelector() {
    // Could be less horrible with C++14 constexpr functions
    // std::is_base_of acts as a demo of complex compile-time conditions
    return std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value + std::is_base_of<BaseB, T>::value * 2;
  } // **1

  template<typename S> using Inner = InnerImpl<S, computeSelector()>;
};
```

The problem is that this way it is not extendable at all.

Outer is dependent to ***all*** possible T, which could easily lead to circular header dependency.

Is there any solution that Outer is not dependent to T?

Comment: Do you only need two potential implementations of `Inner<U>`? In what way do you want it to be extendable?

Comment: More than two potential implementations. In the real scenario, BaseA, BaseB and Outer lives in different headers (and logically different modules). Thus I want to eliminate the dep that Outer deps on every involved types.

Comment: What I desire: if type Outer is not used in a translations unit, the translation unit does not have to include all relavant headers for BaseA, BaseB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your problem but I've tried to semplify your example.

What's wrong with the following solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct BaseA { static constexpr int va = 111; };
struct BaseB { static constexpr int vb = 222; };

struct C : public BaseA {};
struct D : public BaseB {};

template<typename T>
struct Outer
 {
   template <typename S, bool B = true>
   struct InnerI;

   template <typename S>
   struct InnerI<S, std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value>
    { static constexpr int v { T::va }; };

   template <typename S>
   struct InnerI<S, std::is_base_of<BaseB, T>::value>
    { static constexpr int v { T::vb }; };

   template <typename S>
   using Inner = InnerI<S>;
 };


int main()
 {
   std::cout << Outer<C>::Inner<int>::v    << std::endl;    // print 111
   std::cout << Outer<D>::Inner<long>::v   << std::endl;    // print 222
   // std::cout << Outer<int>::Inner<char>::v << std::endl; // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: What I desire: if type Outer is not used in a translations unit, the translation unit does not have to include all relavant headers for BaseA, BaseB, etc. std::is_base_of requires definition of parameter type, which will introduce header dependency.